# How to get current value from a BehaviorSubject in AngularFire2?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, behaviorsubject

I'm using AngularFireDatabase to get part of my database like this `db.object('/accounts/'+this.cid);` where `this.cid` is a `BehaviorSubject` which can change. Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
cid: BehaviorSubject<string>;
account: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.cid = new BehaviorSubject<string>('fs2ejD4ds');
  this.account = db.object('/accounts/'+this.cid);
```

Basically whenever I run `this.cid.next('fhEj2jd')` I want it to change which object we're trying to reference in Firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting current value from `BehaviorSubject`, you can call it's `getValue` method, see **[docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md#rxbehaviorsubjectprototypegetvalue)**.

```
this.account = db.object('/accounts/'+this.cid.getValue());
```

But keep in mind that you will have to overwrite the original observable `this.account` each time `this.cid`'s current value has been changed. And If you simply subscribe to `this.account`, then you will have to unsubscribe before overwrite it with new observable(for unsubscribe, you can use async pipe to do it automatically).

Refer simple **[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/9kbzdsX5Excap9QWdeKA?p=preview)**.